# Universal Links - Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed for UIAlertController

Tags: ios9, uialertcontroller, ios-universal-links

I am pretty sure that it is a framework bug but just to make sure - did someone else have this problem and found a solution?

When I click on a universal link and my opens - I am getting the following error in the console:

Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior ()

There is no UIAlertController used at this point in the app - its just a view controller which has a web view - thats all.

Can someone help me or should I send a bug report?

Br Chris

Comment: Any solutions Chris K??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a bug of iOS9. I'm having a similar issue, so I created a very simple project and tested w/iOS9 (iphone6+) and iOS10 (iphone7+). For my case, the error message appeared at UIDocumentInteractionController AND when I chose apple's apps (e.g., email). The error message came only w/ iOS9. So, I think this is just a bug of iOS9 and I'm simply ignoring. Here is the code.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController! = nil
  @IBAction func openDocInteraction(_ sender: Any) {
    if (documentInteractionController == nil) {
        documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()
    }
    let pngfile = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/testfile.png"
    documentInteractionController.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pngfile)
    documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
  }
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```